# VS tell me that the cast is redundant, but it won't return the correct datatype even without

Tags: c#, casting

Bear with me: I have a very simple comparison, between a value, contained in a dictionary, which is an int, and a float.

Before the comparison, I divide the value by 100, so I get a decimal value (the int is 50, divide by 100, get 0.5).

```
baseline = 0f;
if ((mydict["intvalue"] / 100) > baseline)
    ...do something
```

0.5 is greater than 0.0, so it should "do someting".

Now, the comparison fail all the times; because an int divided by 100, where the result is between 0 and 1, will end up being an int with value 0, from what I can see.
I did cast the value; to solve the issue, but VS tell me that the cast is redundant; and either way, the result is still 0. I don't get what I am doing wrong here.

```
baseline = 0f;
if ((float)(mydict["intvalue"] / 100) > baseline)
    ...do something
```

The compiler tell me that the cast is not necessary, but even if I leave the cast there; I still get 0.

Comment: you are dividing two integers. you could do it like this: `if ((mydict["intvalue"] / 100.0) > baseline)`

Comment: `if ((mydict["intvalue"] / 100.0) > baseline)`

Comment: 0.5 will equate to 0 when cast as an int.

Comment: Yup, both your statements are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `float` casting should be done in one of the items (either `mydict["intvalue"]` or `100`) and *not* their result:

```
//here is one correct way of doing it
if (((float)mydict["intvalue"] / 100) > baseline)

//alternatively
if ((mydict["intvalue"] / 100f) > baseline)
```

What you do before is having integer division, *and then* you cast to float and therefore it is redundant:

```
//note that here you do division first before casting to float
if ((float)(mydict["intvalue"] / 100) > baseline)
```

Comment: And that's why I should have check the order of the braces....I was casting the result, not the dictionary value. Thanks!! That would explain also why VS is telling me that the cast is useless

Comment: True, you get it. ;) yes, in this case, usually compiler knows better than us since our eyes can easily mistaken where we put the parentheses. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or implicit cast like this

```
if (mydict["intvalue"] / 100f > baseline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
if ((float)(mydict["intvalue"] / 100) > baseline)
```

says: Get int divde by int and result also int cast to float. So you need to modify code to operate on floats:

```
if (((float)mydict["intvalue"] / 100) > baseline)
```

or

```
if ((mydict["intvalue"] / 100f) > baseline)
```

Comment: I did meant to cast the dict value, but got confused with the braces; and ended up casting the result; which logically is still 0 even if cast in float. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
(float)(mydict["intvalue"] / 100) > baseline
```

this code run in this order.

mydict["intvalue"]=50

```
(float)(mydict["intvalue"] / 100) > baseline => (float)(50 / 100) > baseline
```

50 / 100 = 0 here is the problem

```
(float)(50 / 100) > baseline => (float)0 > baseline
```

(float)0=0.0f

```
(float)0 > baseline => 0.0f>0.0f =>false
```